# Android Studio Buttons Matrix won't show

Tags: android, button, matrix, dimensions

I am new to Android development and I've made myself a Matrix of buttons in Android Studio. The problem is when I am trying to set the size of the buttons, they won't show up in the app. Works pretty fine without setting the size, but they don't fit in my TableLayout. If I added the buttons manually 9 per row, and 9 rows, they showed up and worked with my dimensions.
Here's the part of the code where I am creating the Buttons.

```
  Button[][] btnTag = new Button[9][9];
    private void createb()
    {
        int k=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
           row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {

                  btnTag[i][j] = new Button(this);
                  btnTag[i][j].setText("");
                  k++;
                  btnTag[i][j].setId(k);
                  row.addView( btnTag[i][j],30,30);
            }
            layout.addView(row);

        }


    }
```

Can you help me to set the size to 30x30dp and still show up ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more info. What is 'layout' here? How does you XML file looks like? What is shown on the screen?

Comment: layout is my Table layout created. layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabel);

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to set the width and height of the Button would be something similar to this:

```
btnTag[i][j].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30, 30));
```

And then

```
row.addView(btnTag[i][j])
```

Answer (score 0):

add your xml.The error to set size might be in the xml file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Found out by myself. Looks like the dimmension here `row.addView( btnTag[i][j],30,30);` is in px and had to put it a little higher (100,100) . Thanks a lot for your time guys!